# Guava: Is it possible not map all entries with Multimaps.index()?

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I have a collection of files, some of them do not meet some requirements and some others that are OK. I would like to do, in one iteration, an indexation of those files and the discard of the useless ones.
I´d like to do it in one iteration as the number is rather large.

So, I was thinking in using Multimaps.index():

```
// This is the file list to work on
Collection<File> fileList = FileUtils.listFiles(pathToCtrFiles,
                                                new String[]{"gz"},false);

// Now I want to index the files according to some condition in the file name (a pattern)
ImmutableListMultimap<ENBEquipment, File> mappedFiles = Multimaps.index(fileList, 
new Function<File,ENBEquipment>()
{
    @Override
    public ENBEquipment apply(File input)
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input.getName());
        if (m.matches()){
            return enodebByMacroEnbIdMap.get(m.group(2));
        }

        // I am not interesting in these files. What can I do?
        return null;
    }
});
```

However, it is not possible to do it as specified in the API:

> Throws:
>   NullPointerException - if any of the following cases is true: 
>   values is null 
>   keyFunction is null 
>   An element in values is null 
>   keyFunction returns null for any element of values

So my question is, do you have an elegant way to do this, without iterating over the file list twice?

Note: I was thinking in returning a dummy element, but the list returned is immutable (no chance of deleting it).

Comment: Cant we derive a class from ENBEquipment say "DummyENBEquipment", override the methods and do no operations. return new DummyENBEquipment where you return null.

Comment: That is complicated as the method is part of an API. The client will not know anything abouth that derived class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the indexing manually in that case (you aren't even really indexing if you're leaving some of the values out).

```
ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<ENBEquipment, File> builder =
    ImmutableListMultimap.builder();
for (File file : fileList) {
  Matcher m = p.matcher(file.getName());
  if (m.matches()) {
    builder.put(enodebByMacroEnbIdMap.get(m.group(2)), file);
  }
}
ImmutableListMultimap<ENBEquipment, File> mappedFiles = builder.build();
```

It comes out to fewer lines and is more readable anyway.

Comment: This is what I finally did as well. I guess that Guava is not silver bullet anyway... PS. Credits to the `ImmutableListMultimap.builder();` I was not aware of that

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the dummy element when you create a new list. But using a dummy is not very clean.

I guess, you can simply filter the `fileList` before you pass it into `Multimaps.index`. The filtering predicate should simply test if your anonymous function returns non `null`.

Comment: That is what I wanted to avoid, filtering the list twice :)